# Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

I am tring to run run wordpress in a localnetwork with the help of xammp . I tried fixing it by pasting wordpress folder after extracting in c-disk in htdocs in xampp folder and other folder but its not working . please help me fixing this issue , attaching screenshots will rather help me more , thanks !!!